# issue with importing image in django project

Tags: django

```
#home{
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 3px 200px;
    height: 921px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
#home::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("{% static 'Image/Bg2.jpg'%}") no-repeat center center/cover;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 87px;
    left: 0;
    height:840px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.78; 
}
```

This is my code in style.css of my Django project. I am unable to import this image when I am running my server.

My Project structure looks like this

Project 4
|----App1
|--migration
|--static
|     |---CSS
|     |    |---style.css
|     |--Image
|          |---Bg2.jpg
|--template
|---index.html

I had two folders in my static folder.

My path to the image is  (  "My Project/My app/static folder/Image folder/My_image" ).

I imported this image in my CSS file.

I tried below URLs also

`background:url("../Image/Bg2.jpg").`

I just want my image to be available I run my server localhost:8000/index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template engine will not evaluate your static files. You need to refer to the file without the template brackets.

If your [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATIC_URL) is `static/`, then use the following path in your CSS file:

```
background-image: url("/static/Image/Bg2.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
```